# exam sample, curious if i got it right

Tags: java

The question is:

Suppose `o` is a reference of type `Object` that is pointing to a type `A` object that contains a `f` method and a `toString` method. Both `toString` and `f` have no parameters. show the statement that calls the `toString` method and the statement that calls the `f` method.

is the answer:

```
 f();
 toString();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not right.  First of all, you're not using the instance `o` to invoke the methods.  Without specifying an instance the compiler would cause those methods to be implicitly called on `this`.

Second, you can't invoke `o.f()` since `f` is not a method of `Object`.  An explicit cast is required to tell the compiler that `o` is of type `A`.

```
Object o = new A();
String s = o.toString();
((A)o).f();
```

### See Also

- [Inheritance (the Java Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the scope in which you are invoking the function.  If you are calling `f` and `toString` in instance methods of the `A` class, then you are correct.

If you are calling `f` and `toString` in static methods of the `A` class, or any method of other classes, then you will need to instantiate a new `A` object, then call the functions on it, like so:

```
A myA = new A();  // Assuming the existence of a no-args constructor
myA.f();
myA.toString();
```

If your reference is strictly of the type `Object`, then you cannot invoke `f`, unless you first cast it to type `A`.

Comment: As Mark points out, since `o` is of type `Object`, even though it is referencing an instance of `A`, a cast is needed to invoke `f`.

Comment: @TedHopp Mark Peters's answer is clearly correct, but for my own edification: isn't that what I've said by "If your reference is strictly of the type `Object`, then you cannot invoke `f`, unless you first cast it to type `A`"?

Comment: Yes. I think I posted my comment before you added that.